# Where is AfterBuildCompiler (msbuild) target defined?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild, target

I'm trying to get multi-project ASP.NET MVC areas (like described [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1483660.aspx/1)) working in MVC 3 on .NET 4 (since it's not officially supported since MVC 2 Beta). So i've found Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build.dll from MVC 2 Preview and modified the script so it can use the assembly directly (it's not strong-named):

```
<UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build.CreateAreaManifest" AssemblyFile="..\..\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build.dll" />
<UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build.CopyAreaManifests" AssemblyFile="..\..\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build.dll" />
```

But i get "error MSB4057: The target "AfterBuildCompile" does not exist in the project.". Where is this target defined?

Found a lot of related posts but none working. Should i abandon the hope to have multi-project areas or try MVCContrib portable areas as alternative (looks not what i need at first glance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the [following article](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/#axzz1I0C6Gjgc).